# How to wrap text in a hyperlink ONLY if it isn't already wrapped in a hyperlink

Tags: regex

I need to do a regex replacement where I take a string and wrap a hyperlink around it (but here's the catch) as long as it isn't already surrounded by a hyperlink. How would I do this?

So, for example, let's take the text:

```
The quick brown fox.
```

I want to make "quick brown" a link, like this:

```
The <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">quick brown</a> fox.
```

But if I find the text:

```
The <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">quick brown</a> fox.
```

I want to be sure that I don't wrap "quick brown" in another hyperlink.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Lookarounds could get you somewhere. Though not perfect at all, here is a quick regex check to see whether your text has been wrapped in anchor tags already.

```
(?<=>)quick brown(?=</a>)
```

Note: lookbehind assertions need to be fixed length (at least in PCRE).

Answer (score 1):

If the string you want to wrap a link around is `YOUR_STRING`, first identify all places where `YOUR_STRING` is surrounded by a link tag.

regex = `<a[^>]*>[^<]*(YOUR_STRING)[^<]*</a>`

Starts with `<a`

Followed by a sequence of length zero or more that doesn't contain `>` .

Followed by `>`

Followed by a sequence of length zero or more that doesn't contain `<`.

Followed by `YOUR_STRING`  This is a capturing group.

Followed by a sequence of length zero or more that doesn't contain `<`.

Followed by `</a>`

Now you can identify the character offsets of the places where captured group `YOUR_STRING` is surrounded by a link tag.

Other than these places, in all other places where `YOUR_STRING` occurs literally, wrap the link tag around it.

**Bonus point**: Note that when you insert text into a string, you may change the character offsets, OR your regex may throw a ConcurrentModificationException / not allow you to insert text during analysis time (depending on what library you are using). The best way to handle this is to create a separate StringBuffer and append text to it as your analyze your original string.

Also note: The regex to identify the hyperlink tag can be written more smarter (for correct html) but this should work for bad html too. E.g. with a missing href attribute such as `<a>quick brown fox</a>`. If the html you are expecting can be imperfect and you would like to handle those issues, then you should modify the regex accordingly.

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking at the keywords, it may be easier to just do a simple match on the url and only do the keyword replacement if the url is not found in the 'raw' html

Comment: that would solve the second problem of identifying when the link exists, but would not identify words that need the link but do not yet have it.

Answer (score 0):

it seems as if you are parsing rendered html, if that is the case why not parse the raw html?  Then the problem becomes trivial

Comment: I don't see how it becomes trivial. I don't understand the difference between raw and rendered html. html is a format. The browser renders the format into an interface.

The documents I'm using the regex against are html documents. So there's no way to remove the html.