# Regular expression to find URLs not inside a hyperlink

Tags: html, regex, url

There's many regex's out there to match a URL.  However, I'm trying to match URLs that do not appear anywhere within a `<a>` hyperlink tag (`HREF`, inner value, etc.).  So NONE of the URLs in these should match:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/">something</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/">http://www.example2.com</a>
<a href="http://www.example.com/"><b>something</b>http://www.example.com/<span>test</span></a>
```

Any URL outside of `<a></a>` should be matched.

One approach I tried was to use a negative lookahead to see if the first `<a>` tag after the URL was an opening `<a>` or a closing `</a>`.  If it is a closing `</a>` then the URL must be inside a hyperlink.  I think this idea was okay, but the negative lookahead regex didn't work (or more accurately, the regex wasn't written correctly).  Any tips are very appreciated.

Comment: What platform? Perl, .NET or Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap text in a hyperlink ONLY if it isn't already wrapped in a hyperlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191637/how-to-wrap-text-in-a-hyperlink-only-if-it-isnt-already-wrapped-in-a-hyperlink)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in two steps instead of trying to come up with a single regular expression:

1. Blend out (replace with nothing) the HTML anchor part (the entire anchor tag: opening tag, content and closing tag).
2. Match the URL

In Perl it could be:

```
my $curLine = $_; #Do not change $_ if it is needed for something else.
$curLine =~ /<a[^<]+<\/a>//g; #Remove all of HTML anchor tag, "<a", "</a>" and everything in between.
if ( $curLine =~ /http:\/\//)
{
  print "Matched an URL outside a HTML anchor !: $_\n";
}
```

Comment: If I remove (blend out) the HTML anchors, I won't be able to determine if the URL was originally inside a hyperlink, right?  I'm only looking for URLs that are outside hyperlink tags.

Comment: I mean: remove *everything* from the opening anchor tag till the closing anchor tag.

Comment: Ah, great solution.  I got it working.  At first I thought you meant to just remove the beginning and ending tags, but removing the whole tag was the trick.  Thank you!!

Comment: -1 You should remove the <a> elements through a proper parser, since HTML is not a regular language.

Comment: @Svante: I don't think this is fair. Shouldn't it be directed towards the question instead? The question was about matching with regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for this answer as well and because nothing out there really worked like I wanted it too this is the regex that I created. Obviously since its a regex be aware that this is not a perfect solution.

```
/(?!<a[^>]*>[^<])(((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))(?![^<]*<\/a>)/gi
```

And the whole function to update html is:

```
function linkifyWithRegex(input) {
  let html = input;
  let regx = /(?!<a[^>]*>[^<])(((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?))(?![^<]*<\/a>)/gi;
  html = html.replace(
    regx,
    function (match) {
      return '<a href="' + match + '">' + match + "</a>";
    }
  );
  return html;
}
```

Comment: https://regexr.com/7cab0
It seems to me it doesn't work. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using a single regular expression that matches both anchor tags and hyperlinks:

```
# Note that this is a dummy, you'll need a more sophisticated URL regex
regex = '(<a[^>]+>)|(http://.*)'
```

Then loop over the results and only process matches where the second sub-pattern was found.

Comment: This only works for those URLs that are inside the tag, not for those inside an <a> element.  Also, it tries to parse a non-regular language with regular expressions.

Comment: @Svante: First, you can easily extend the example to match everything within <a...> and </a>. Then it does the same as the accepted answer, only in a single pass. Second, no, "it" does not try to parse anything but a regular language based on occurrences of HTML-ish strings. There is no need to use a full-featured HTML parser if all you want is find simple pattern in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Peter has a great answer: first, remove anchors so that

```
Some text <a href="http://page.net">TeXt</a> and some more text with link http://a.net
```

is replaced by

```
Some text  and some more text with link http://a.net
```

THEN run a regexp that finds urls:

```
http://a.net
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM to filter out the anchor elements, then do a simple URL regex on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^.*<(a|A){1,1}  ->scan until >a or >A is found
 .*(href|HREF){1,1}\=  -> scan until href= or HREF=
  \x22{1,1}.*\x22  -> accept all characters between two quotes
  > -> look for >
  .+(|){1,1} -> accept description and end anchor tag
  $ -> End of string search


    pattern= "^.*<(a|A){1,1}.*(href|HREF){1,1}.*\=.*\x22{0,1}.*\x22{0,1}.*>.+(|){1,1}$"
```