# Regular expression check by skipping anchor tags

Tags: php, regex

I have written a regex for searching particular keyword and I am replacing that keyword with particular URL.

My current regex is as: `\b$keyword\b`

One problem in this is that if my data contains anchor tags and that tag contains this keyword then this regex replaces that keyword in the anchor tag as well.

I want to search in given data excluding anchor tag. Please help me out. Appreciate your help.

eg.  Keyword: Disney

I/p:

```
This is <a href="/test.php"> Disney </a> The disney should be replaceable
```

Expected O/p:

```
This is <a href="/test.php"> Disney </a> The <a href="any-url.php">disney</a> should be replaceable
```

Invalid o/p:

```
This is <a href="/test.php"> <a href="any-url.php">Disney</a> </a> The <a href="any-url.php">disney</a> should be replaceable
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that your expected and invalid strings are the same.

Comment: @Grim:Thanks. I have corrected it now

Comment: This question is basically the same as yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315653/regular-expression-to-find-urls-not-inside-a-hyperlink

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified my function that highlights searched phrase on a page, here you go:

```
$html = 'This is <a href="/test.php"> Disney </a> The disney should be replaceable.'.PHP_EOL;
$html .= 'Let\'s test also use of keyword inside other tags, for example as class name:'.PHP_EOL;
$html .= '<b class=disney></b> - this should not be replaced with link, and it isn\'t!'.PHP_EOL;

$result = ReplaceKeywordWithLink($html, "disney", "any-url.php");
echo nl2br(htmlspecialchars($result));

function ReplaceKeywordWithLink($html, $keyword, $link)
{
    if (strpos($html, "<") !== false) {
        $id = 0;
        $unique_array = array();
        // Hide existing anchor tags with some unique string.
        preg_match_all("#<a[^<>]*>[\s\S]*?</a>#i", $html, $matches);
        foreach ($matches[0] as $tag) {
            $id++;
            $unique_string = "@@@@@$id@@@@@";
            $unique_array[$unique_string] = $tag;
            $html = str_replace($tag, $unique_string, $html);
        }
        // Hide all tags by replacing with some unique string.
        preg_match_all("#<[^<>]+>#", $html, $matches);      
        foreach ($matches[0] as $tag) {
            $id++;
            $unique_string = "@@@@@$id@@@@@";
            $unique_array[$unique_string] = $tag;
            $html = str_replace($tag, $unique_string, $html);
        }
    }
    // Then we replace the keyword with link.
    $keyword = preg_quote($keyword);
    assert(strpos($keyword, '$') === false);
    $html = preg_replace('#(\b)('.$keyword.')(\b)#i', '$1<a href="'.$link.'">$2</a>$3', $html);
    // We get back all the tags by replacing unique strings with their corresponding tag.
    if (isset($unique_array)) {     
        foreach ($unique_array as $unique_string => $tag) {
            $html = str_replace($unique_string, $tag, $html);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Result:

```
This is <a href="/test.php"> Disney </a> The <a href="any-url.php">disney</a> should be replaceable.
Let's test also use of keyword inside other tags, for example as class name:
<b class=disney></b> - this should not be replaced with link, and it isn't!
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the end of your regex:

```
(?=[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*(?:<a\b|\z))
```

This [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) tries to match either the next opening `<a>` tag or the end of the input, but only if it doesn't see a closing `</a>` tag first.  Assuming the HTML is minimally well formed, the lookahead will fail whenever the match starts after the beginning of an `<a>` tag and before the corresponding `</a>` tag.

To prevent it from matching inside any other tag (e.g. `<div class="disney">`), you can add this lookahead as well:

```
(?![^<>]*+>)
```

With this one I'm assuming there won't be any angle brackets in the attribute values of the tags, which is legal according to the HTML 4 spec, but extremely rare in the real world.

If you're writing the regex in the form of a PHP double-quoted string (which you must be, if you expect the `$keyword` variable to be replaced) you should double all the backslashes.  `\z` probably wouldn't be a problem but I believe `\b` would be interpreted as a backspace, not as a word-boundary assertion.

**EDIT:** On second thought, definitely do add the second lookahead--I mean, why would *not* want to prevent matches inside tags?  And place it first, because it will tend to evaluate more quickly than the other:

```
(?![^<>]*+>)(?=[^<]*(?:<(?!/?a\b)[^<]*)*(?:<a\b|\z))
```

Comment: Did you tested these regexes? Your solution seems interesting, but I don't think that it actually would work, there are probably more exceptions, that 1 line of regex just can't serve them all.

Comment: @Czarek, there are many things that can cause this solution to fail, including CDATA sections, SGML comments, `<script>` and `<style>` elements, angle brackets in attribute values, and of course, invalid HTML.  But that's true of almost every regex-based solution, including yours.  Strictly speaking, it's impossible to process HTML with regexes, but we do it anyway.  As long as you're aware of the limitations, this technique is as safe as any; I've used it many times.

Comment: @Czarek: ...but +1 to your answer, too.  I've never seen that technique implemented so thoroughly before.

Answer (score 0):

strip the tags first, then search on the stripped text.

Comment: I want those anchor tags there in the data, so I can't use strip_tags for this